# How to simply export a method to another .js file to be included with <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, include

I would like to export a function to another file so that I can include it later as every other library that one can use:

`toogle.js`

```
var toggle = function(){
...
}
```

`index.html`

```
<script src="../lib/toggle.js"></script>
```

How can I do that to use `toggle` function in my code ?

Comment: Import your toggle.js file first :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: There are many ways for this. Check [`browserify `](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a global Namespace that is shared between scripts.

This way you can simply add to the namespace as necessary.

In `main.js` in `<head>`.

```
/**
 * @Namespace Toggle
 */
(function(Toggle) {

    /**
     * Function description
     * @method      method1
     * @memberof    Toggle
     * @return      void
     */
    Toggle.method1 = function() {};

    /**
     * Function description
     * @method      method2
     * @memberof    Toggle
     * @return      void
     */
    Toggle.method2 = function() {};

})(window["Toggle"] || window["Toggle"] = Object.create(null));
```

In `<script>` tag in `<body>`.

```
document.onload = (function(Toggle) {

    Toggle.method1();
    Toggle.method2();

}).bind(window["Toggle"} || window["Toggle"] = Object.create(null));
```

#### Tools

The following tools can help you do this automatically so you can focus on other things.

- Webpack ([webpack.io](http://webpack.github.io))
- TypeScript ([typescriptlang.io](https://www.typescriptlang.org))

Answer (score -1):

Instead of what you have, try putting this in `toggle.js`:

```
function toggle() {
    code to be executed
}
```

Then in `index.html` you can use it normally by calling `toggle()`.